# Pass one resource's variable to another

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating an Azure App Service resource and an App Registration resource (and app service and others that are not relevant to this question as they work fine) via Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app" {
  name                = var.app_service_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.plan-app.id

  app_settings = {
    "AzureAd:ClientId" = azuread_application.appregistration.application_id
  }

  site_config {
    ftps_state = var.app_service_ftps_state
  }
}

resource "azuread_application" "appregistration" {
  display_name                   = azurerm_app_service.app.name
  owners                         = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience               = "AzureADMyOrg"
  fallback_public_client_enabled = true

  web {
    homepage_url  = var.appreg_web_homepage_url
    logout_url    = var.appreg_web_logout_url
    redirect_uris = [var.appreg_web_homepage_url, var.appreg_web_redirect_uri]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }
}

output "appreg_application_id" {
  value = azuread_application.appregistration.application_id
}
```

I need to add the App Registration client / application id to the `app_settings` block in the app service resource.

The error I get with the above configuration is:

```
{"@level":"error","@message":"Error: Cycle: azuread_application.appregistration, azurerm_app_service.app","@module":"terraform.ui","@timestamp":"2021-09-15T10:54:31.753401Z","diagnostic":{"severity":"error","summary":"Cycle: azuread_application.appregistration, azurerm_app_service.app","detail":""},"type":"diagnostic"}
```

Note that the output variable displays the application id correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a cycle error because you have both resources referencing each other. [Terraform builds a directed acyclical graph](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/graph.html) to work out which order to create (or destroy) resources in with the information from one resource or data source flowing into another normally determining this order.

In your case your `azuread_application.appregistration` resource is referencing the `azurerm_app_service.app.name` parameter while the `azurerm_app_service.app` resource needs the `azuread_application.appregistration.application_id` attribute.

I don't know a ton about Azure but to me that seems like the [`azurerm_app_service` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service) needs to be created ahead of the [`azuread_application` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application) and so I'd expect the link to be in that direction.

Because you are already setting the `azurerm_app_service.app.name` parameter to `var.app_service_name` then you can just directly pass `var.app_service_name` to `azuread_application.appregistration.display_name` to achieve the same result but to break the cycle error.

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app" {
  name                = var.app_service_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.plan-app.id

  app_settings = {
    "AzureAd:ClientId" = azuread_application.appregistration.application_id
  }

  site_config {
    ftps_state = var.app_service_ftps_state
  }
}

resource "azuread_application" "appregistration" {
  display_name                   = var.app_service_name
  owners                         = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience               = "AzureADMyOrg"
  fallback_public_client_enabled = true

  web {
    homepage_url  = var.appreg_web_homepage_url
    logout_url    = var.appreg_web_logout_url
    redirect_uris = [var.appreg_web_homepage_url, var.appreg_web_redirect_uri]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }
}

output "appreg_application_id" {
  value = azuread_application.appregistration.application_id
}
```